# How to use onmouseover on a header?

Tags: jsp, onmouseover

I am working on a new application. It has common header.
for a small `<div>`class, i have following code.

```
<div class="toolbox">
<span class="arrow"></span>
<h3>User Menu</h3>
<ul class="mail">
<span><img src="images/icons/help.png" alt="mail" style="float:left;"></span>
<li>
<a href="#"><strong>Help!</strong>
<small>
Application Help</small></a>
</li>
<span><img src="images/icons/about.png" alt="mail" style="float:left;"></span>
<li>
<a href="#"><strong>About</strong>
<small>
About
</small></a>
</li>
<span><img src="images/icons/logout.png" alt="mail" style="float:left;"></span>
</li>
<a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />"><strong>Logout</strong>
<small>
Logout From The Application
</small></a>\
</li>
</ul>
<span class="inbox" href="#"><sec:authentication property="principal.username" /> is logged-in</span>
</div>
```

After click on toolbox,  a menu appears with 3 items, 
I want these items using `onmouseover`.
please help

Comment: And this code is in CSS      .toolbox {   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="toolbox">
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    <h3>User Menu</h3>
    <div id="showMenu">
        <ul class="mail">
            <span><img src="images/icons/help.png" alt="mail" style="float:left;"></span>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><strong>Help!</strong>
                <small>Application Help</small></a>
            </li>
            <span><img src="images/icons/about.png" alt="mail" style="float:left;"></span>
            <li>
                <strong>About</strong>
                <small>
                    About
                </small>
            </li>
            <span><img src="images/icons/logout.png" alt="mail" style="float:left;"></span>
            <li>
                <a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />">
                   <strong>Logout</strong>
                   <small>
                       Logout From The Application
                </small></a>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="inbox" href="#"><sec:authentication property="principal.username" /> is logged-in</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#showMenu
{
    display:none;
}
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toolbox').hover();
});

$('.toolbox').hover(function(){
    $('#showMenu').slideDown();
});

$('.toolbox').mouseout(function(){
    $('#showMenu').slideUp();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VAfB7/)

Comment: this is not working, i think problem in script. please re-write it.